# I've noticed sometimes run_coroutine_threadsafe did skip the task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

And I have made an application which wait for a task to run soon but doesn't wait to get the result but I've noticed sometimes

`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` did skip some task and it randomly runs by no order.

I integrated this with flask covered with uwsgi (processes = 1, threads = 10)
`run_coroutine_threadsafe` can possibly call by any threads at the same time

```py
# get asyncio event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# define function to run in a thread
def InitAsyncio(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

# create asyncio to run in thread
t = threading.Thread(target=InitAsyncio, args=(loop,))
t.start()

async def ProcessPicture(InputInt):
    try:
        print("This is a book. %d" % InputInt)
        return
    except:
        return

def main():
  for i in range(1000):
   asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(ProcessPicture(i), loop)
```

How to ensure that `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` always runs by no skip and order the task to run

Comment: By "skip some task" do you mean that the task wouldn't get done at all, or that it would get done out of order? If it is the former, are you sure that the task didn't fail with some exception? Note that `run_coroutine_threadsafe` **returns** an object (instance of `concurrent.futures.Future`, not to be confused with an asyncio future) which you can use to obtain the result of the coroutine, or to check whether it's done. Accessing the result will propagate the exception raised by the task, if any.

Comment: I am sure that some task gets skip because I put an exception to track error but I got nothing print out

Comment: Have you tried accessing the `result` as reported by the future object returned by run_coroutine_threadsafe?

Comment: i do understand now what i understand is, by running run_coroutine_threadsafe it doesn't throw exception by it self and question how can i catch an exception that trow by run_coroutine_threadsafe

Comment: As mentioned previously, `run_coroutine_threadsafe` **returns** [an object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) that holds the result or the exception. You are currently discarding it, but you can keep it in a variable and e.g. call [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback) to be notified when the coroutine is done. Most importantly, you can use its `result()` method to access the result or the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread ends before tasks are added into loop. Add `time.sleep(5)` in main and you will see it works well.